# Xamarin Android.Support.V4 in VS 2013 not recognize in amxl.layout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I am working with VS 2013 and I have already installed Components and references.

[The main.axml does not recognize that layout. The warning is: Invalid child element 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager'. List of possible elements expected (all of the VS 2013 Toolbox):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNBS.png)

I already included the 'Xamarin.Android.Support v4' library and a Reference exists to my Project. 
I tried: 'Manage NuGet Packages' and 'Installed it with Package Manager Console but it still does not work.
It only works in my CS.Files.
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be of great help for you, but I recently faced the same issue (with VS 2015), turns out that if you type the namespace from the support library correctly, it will give you this alerts but it will work anyway...

In *Tools* > *Extensions and Updates* you might find something that adds support to that.

Below is a example of a drawer layout that i used (and it works), with the same issue you reported.

[image: invalid child element, but working, example]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to build my project but now I got the error message
"Error 2 The process cannot access the file 'classes.jar' because it is being used by another process. App1".  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Not really, I think you could try to close all open files inside VS, then clean and rebuild. If that doesn't work, close VS, open the task manager and kill the process(if there's any) related to your app1, then try to open and build it again..